# Dealing with non-BMP Characters in Python

Tags: python

I have non-BMP characters appearing frequently in the text I'm trying to print, which is causing many errors like this in my IDLE window:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 18-18: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

I would like to parse the text before printing it, find these characters, and replace them with `\uFFFD` (�) so that the python program doesn't crash, and also returns something so I, the user, can see that a non-BMP character was there.

Comment: What Python version are you using? How are you decoding your string? Are you explicitly calling `decode()` or something else? Did you take a look at the [codecs error handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers)?

Comment: @glibdud pretty sure that's it, I didn't see that, thanks for letting me know :) when my code runs across the issue again, if it works, I'll mark it as solved.